# Integrity constraint (JAVAUSER.SYS_C007925) violated - parent key not found

Tags: sql, database

SQL Error

I'm not sure what I did wrong here

Here is the DDL I used to create my tables

```
Create Table HomeState (StateAbbreviation char(2) Primary Key,
        StateName varchar(25));

Create Table Country (CountryAbbreviation char(2) Primary Key,
          CountryName varchar(35));

Create Table Employee (EmployeeID Integer Primary Key NOT NULL,
                       FirstName varchar(20),
                       LastName varchar(30),
                       MI char(1),
                       HomeAddress varchar(30),
                       Zip char(5),
                       DateOfBirth date,
                       HireDate date,
                       TerminationDate date,
                       AnnualSalary number(20,2),
                       LicenseDate date,
                       StateAbbreviation char(2),
                       CountryAbbreviation char(2),
                       Foreign Key (StateAbbreviation) references HomeState,
                       Foreign Key (CountryAbbreviation) references Country);

Create Table Truck (VinNumber Integer Primary Key,
            Make varchar(25),
            Model varchar(30),
            Year Integer,
            PurchasePrice number(20,2),
            LicenseNumber varchar(15));

Create Table EmployeeTruck (EmployeeID Integer,
            VinNumber Integer,
            Primary Key(EmployeeID,VinNumber),
            Foreign Key (EmployeeID) references Employee,
            Foreign Key (VinNumber) references Truck);

Create Table Accident (AccidentID Integer Primary Key,
           DateOfAccident date,
           AccidentDescription varchar(200),
           AccidentLocation varchar(100),
           EmployeeID Integer,
           Foreign Key (EmployeeID) references Employee);
```

and here is the command i used to try and fill in the employee table

```
insert into employee 
values ('1','brian','kim','j','adfasdf',
        '1234','24-nov-1993','24-sep-1993','24-sep-1993',
        '1234','24-sep-1993','as','as')
```

but it always gives me the error i put as the title of this question...

Answer (score 0):

In the table "Employee", you say that `Foreign Key (StateAbbreviation) references HomeState`, and `Foreign Key (CountryAbbreviation) references Country)`. The values you insert into Employee.HomeState and Employee.CountryAbbreviation have to exist in the tables HomeState and Country before you can insert into Employee.

Insert rows into HomeState and Country before you insert into Employee.

---

You have other problems, too.  Here's an example.

```
Create Table HomeState (StateAbbreviation char(2) Primary Key,
    StateName varchar(25));

insert into HomeState values ('AL', 'Alabama');
insert into HomeState values ('AM', 'Alabama');
insert into HomeState values ('AN', 'Alabama');
```

All those insert statements succeed. They shouldn't. In this case, StateName is also a candidate key.

```
Create Table HomeState (
    StateAbbreviation char(2) Primary Key,
    StateName varchar(25) not null unique
);
```

Let's take this a little further.

```
Create Table HomeState (
    StateAbbreviation char(2) Primary Key,
    StateName varchar(25) not null unique
);

Create Table Country (
    CountryAbbreviation char(2) Primary Key,
    CountryName varchar(35) not null unique
);

insert into HomeState values ('CA', 'California');
insert into Country values ('AF', 'Afghanistan');

insert into Employee (EmployeeID, StateAbbreviation, CountryAbbreviation)
values (-42, 'CA', 'AF');
```

The state "California, US" makes sense. The state "California, Afghanistan" doesn't.

An employee having no name doesn't make sense. Declare FirstName, LastName, and HireDate `not null`.

Bet on this: whatever nonsense your database allows *will* appear. It's just a matter of time.